# Android JSONArray to ArrayList

Tags: java, android, json, arraylist, arrays

I am trying to parse a JSONArray into and ArrayList in my android app. The PHP script correctly retuns the expected results, however the Java fails with a null pointer exception at `resultsList.add(map)`

```
public void agencySearch(String tsearch)    {
        // Setting the URL for the Search by Town
        String url_search_agency = "http://www.infinitycodeservices.com/get_agency_by_city.php";
        // Building parameters for the search
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("City", tsearch));

        // Getting JSON string from URL
        JSONArray json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url_search_agency, params);

        for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++) {
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

            try {
                JSONObject c = (JSONObject) json.get(i);
                //Fill map
                Iterator iter = c.keys();
                while(iter.hasNext())   {
                    String currentKey = (String) iter.next();
                    map.put(currentKey, c.getString(currentKey));
                }
                resultsList.add(map);

            }
            catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }

        };

        MainActivity.setResultsList(resultsList);

    }
```

Comment: where you initialize `resultsList` in your code?

Comment: That's because `resultsList` is null.

Comment: have you initialize resultList???

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this may help you,

```
public void agencySearch(String tsearch)    {
        // Setting the URL for the Search by Town
        String url_search_agency = "http://www.infinitycodeservices.com/get_agency_by_city.php";
        // Building parameters for the search
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("City", tsearch));

        // Getting JSON string from URL
        JSONArray json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url_search_agency, params);

       ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> resultsList = new  ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++) {
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

            try {
                JSONObject c = json.getJSONObject(position);
                //Fill map
               Iterator<String> iter = c.keys();
                while(iter.hasNext())   {
                    String currentKey = it.next();
                    map.put(currentKey, c.getString(currentKey));
                }
                resultsList.add(map);

            }
            catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }

        };

        MainActivity.setResultsList(resultsList);

    }
```

Comment: Nice catch. My declaration for resultsList was elsewhere in the class code. This was my original definition              ArrayList<Map<String, String>> resultsList;  after adding the = new  ArrayList<Map<String, String>>() to the end of that line the exception was gone. Thanks again. Maybe I should have gotten some sleep and checked it again before asking the question. Simple syntax error. Hopefully it will help someone else as well.

Answer (score 1):

Use custom method which convert your JSONArray to List instead of iterate and build List.

**How to call :**

```
try {
     ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> list = (ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>) toList(json);
} catch (JSONException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**Convert json array to List :**

```
private List toList(JSONArray array) throws JSONException {
    List list = new ArrayList();
    int size = array.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        list.add(fromJson(array.get(i)));
    }
    return list;
}
```

**Convert json to Object :**

```
private Object fromJson(Object json) throws JSONException {
    if (json == JSONObject.NULL) {
        return null;
    } else if (json instanceof JSONObject) {
        return jsonToMap((JSONObject) json);
    } else if (json instanceof JSONArray) {
        return toList((JSONArray) json);
    } else {
        return json;
    }
}
```

**Convert json to map :**

```
public Map<String, String> jsonToMap(JSONObject object) throws JSONException {
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap();
    Iterator keys = object.keys();
    while (keys.hasNext()) {
        String key = (String) keys.next();
        map.put(key, fromJson(object.get(key)).toString());
    }
    return map;
}
```

Comment: Have you try this @IrishCarBomb ?

Comment: I didn't. Is this using the GSON LIB?