# How to Parse JSON without key value in android

Tags: android, json

Hi in my android application  I'm receiving a JSON response from server and it has no key value for it,Now I should parse that JSON and that parsed data should be appended to a spinner. How to achieve that ? This is what I have tried

```
This is my JSON 

    [["Basic","Premium","svdsv","uymyimy"]] 


String url = "http://www.thetaf.com/TAFCycleStation/get_plans.php";

        try {

            JSONArray data = new JSONArray(getJSONUrl(url));

            List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();


            for(int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) 
            {
                JSONObject c = data.getJSONObject(i);

                list.add(c.getString("0"));
            }

            ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
            dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            plans.setAdapter(dataAdapter);


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public String getJSONUrl(String url) {
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
        try {
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
            if (statusCode == 200) { // Download OK
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                InputStream content = entity.getContent();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    str.append(line);
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("Log", "Failed to download result..");
            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return str.toString();
    }
```

Comment: How can it be JSON if it has no key value?

Comment: can you show the json once

Comment: Yes show us the json

Comment: @RanjitPati [["Basic","Premium","svdsv","uymyimy"]] this is my JSON

Comment: AFAIK its not a JSON..

Comment: Check out : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26814673/android-jsonarray-to-arraylist

Comment: @RanjitPati http://jsonlint.com/ says its a valid JSON :)

Answer (score 3):

Try like the following:

```
try {
       JSONArray jsonArray1=new JSONArray(jsonString);
       JSONArray jsonArray2=jsonArray1.getJSONArray(0);
       for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray2.length(); i++) {
              String value=jsonArray2.getString(i);
              System.out.println(value);
       }
} catch (JSONException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Add the `value` to your list as required.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
       JSONArray obj = null;
        try {
            obj = new JSONArray(YOURJSON);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        for (int i=0; i<obj.length(); i++){
            try {
                String extString  = (String) obj.get(i);
                System.out.println("Your string");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

My JSON :

[
    "a",
    "about",
    "above",
    "after",
    "again",
    "against",
    "all",
    "am",
    "an",
    "and",
    "any",
    "are",
    "aren't",
    "as",
    "at",
    "be",
    "because",
    "been",
    "before",
    "being",
    "below",
    "between",
    "both",
    "but",
    "by",
    "can't",
    "cannot"]